# How to pass a function in selected from ember-power-select

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-addon

I have an Ember.js application, and for a form in it, I am using [ember-power-select](http://www.ember-power-select.com/). I already used that addon, but I have some problems with how to configure the `selected` element. As the title say, I am asking for help with how to configure the `selected` with a function.
I want to set the selected variable with a function that retrieve a variable from a services.

My component look like that:

```
import Ember from 'ember'; 

export default Ember.Component.
    appInfo: Ember.inject.service('app-info'),

    languageOption: ['Français', 'English'],
    language() {
       /*
       * In my service appInfo, I have a function called getLocale
       * that return the current locale variable.  
       */
       return this.get('appInfo').getLocale();
       },

       actions: {
           changeLanguage(lang)
           {
              this.set('language', lang);
           }
        }
});
```

And my template look like that:

```
{{#power-select
          selected=language
          options=languageOption
          searchEnabled=false
          onchange=(action 'changeLanguage')
          placeholder=language
        as |lang|}}
          {{lang}}
{{/power-select}}
```

As you can see I'm trying to set my `selected` value with the current `locale` obtained via the service `appInfo`. Everything is working just fine except the selected part.
In the *template*, you can see that 'selected' is a value that can be set within a *component*, except that I don't want to set the value with a hardcoded one, but with the current value of *locale*.
Every tips and/or help is appreciated!

Comment: Does your service pass in the same values that are in your options array? If `this.set('language', lang)` does not match an option it will fail to select. http://www.ember-power-select.com/docs/how-to-use-it

Comment: The thing is it does not fail, it just put the function in plain text in my power-select. Instead of having 'English' for example, I received : `language() {
       /*
       * In my service appInfo, I have a function called getLocale
       * that return the current locale variable.  
       */
       return this.get('appInfo').getLocale();
       },`

Comment: I see, well the initial problem is `language()` is a function instead of a property. But even if it was, the power select docs say that options are read only, so a new one shouldn't be able to be declared. I'll test it myself and see what I can find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved it, I used `init()` to make it work. As @BrandonW said in the comment, a computed property doesn't work too.

This is the code that I putted in my component:

```
***
   init() {
        this._super(...arguments);
        let loc = this.get('appInfo').getLocale();
        if (loc === 'fr')
            this.set('language', 'Français');
        else
            this.set('language', 'English');
    }
***
```

This is what you want to do if you want to use a *function* to set `selected` in ember-power-select addon.